# Hi My problem is with the terminal VS app

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

**PS E:\learning\project\django\env\scripts> activate**

activate : The term 'activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- activate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Try `activate.bat`

Comment: Test result:PS E:\learning\project\django\env\scripts> activate.bat
activate.bat : The term 'activate.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the .................
 

Suggestion [3,General]: The command activate.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\activate.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: Then do `.\activate.bat`

Comment: its ok tnx tnx tnx

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Venv environment and run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUse
```

then run:

```
.\\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

this should activate your venv environment
to deactivate:

```
deactivate
```